# Best Practice Decisions in saving html?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, post, special-characters

I have a client/server application (asp.net), which has a textarea which a user types in `html elements`+`text`.

the data being sent from client to server is via `jQuery ajax  POST`. ( to `ashx`)

lets say the client type in:

```
<b> Hello </b>
```

so I :

1) `encodeUriComponent` the whole text.

2) `Html Encode` Special Chars ( like `&gt; &lt;`)

3) send this to the server

4) save in DB.

Question :

*what is the prefered way of saving in db  ?*

With `&gt; &lt;`? or should I decode it and then save it?

(data should be presented to user, some time in the future...)

Comment: Um... just save it in the database raw. You don't need to URL encode or HTML encode something in order to save it to the database. The only protection you need is against SQL injection, which is easily fulfilled by simply parameterizing all your queries.

Comment: @BoltClock yeah but i cant send it server with tags like <> becuase it will cause exception

Comment: @subt13 what do you thing StackOverlFlow are doing ? when you write a code ?

Comment: @moguzalp: SQL injection is totally unrelated to unescaped HTML or cross-site scripting. Don't mix the two up.

Comment: @moguzalp Im not going to disable request validation.... I need to take care of a problem not disable features....)

Comment: @subt13 I didnt say they are saving the whole html page.... just the portion of your code ( like my question )

Comment: @BoltClock I cant send it ( even if parameters...) http://i.stack.imgur.com/aEb9g.jpg

Comment: @moguzalp, is there a reason you don't like flawn?

Comment: You can use the `[AllowHtml]` attribute on specific properties of your model to allow html characters, such as `<` and `>`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute(v=vs.98).aspx

Comment: @ChristopherHarris  http://i.stack.imgur.com/TgRKw.png

Comment: @moguzalp: security risk, breach, flaw, error, back-door, etc.

Comment: @RoyiNamir, You're missing the point. Skipping request validation is only BAD because people will assume the values are correct and use them as-is. If you have a valid reason to skip validation (such as the fact that you're going to skirt around the whole process anyways by encoding and decoding the html), then you might as well use the attribute Microsoft gave you to do it. They supply that attribute because there are valid reasons to skip request validation for specific peices of data. You need to *be careful* when you do this, though, because that *data could be bad*. Read my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. POST the raw HTML input to your desired action
2. Use the [AllowHtml] attribute on the desired field of your model.
3. Use [Microsoft's Anti-XSS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa973814) library to remove any javascript, etc (unless that's intended).
4. Save raw HTML to your database, but be sure to use parameterized queries to prevent injection attacks.
5. Stop HTML Encoding everything. It looks terrible.

Comment: Im not using MVC. Ive just notice your answer is regard to mvc. Asp.net won't let me _POST the raw HTML_  - it will give an error if I send `<`

Answer (score 0):

You can save it to the database raw, but I highly suggest that you use some sort of parsing to clean the input. You will need to clean non-standard html, and any attempts at javascript, etc. Otherwise it's a huge security risk. You can use the html tidy .net wrapper here.

http://markbeaton.com/SoftwareInfo.aspx?ID=81a0ecd0-c41c-48da-8a39-f10c8aa3f931